# Identityserver4 with resource owner password returning 401 in resource server

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

IDENTITYSERVER4 RESOURCE OWNER PASSWORD FLOW WITH CUSTOM USER REPOSITORY

Created a Identityserver by following this
 [link](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/) 
But in resource server side, I am unable to authorize an API.

Successfully getting access token. [image: Screenshot here]

In ***Start up.cs*** file

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            })
         .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(QuickstartIdentityServer.Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(QuickstartIdentityServer.Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(QuickstartIdentityServer.Config.GetClients())
        .AddCustomUserStore();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
```

Coming to ***Config.cs*** file

```
  public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        // client credentials client
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600, //86400,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600, //86400,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = false,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 30,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                Enabled = true,
                ClientSecrets = 
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedScopes = { "api1", "openid"}
            }
        };
    }
```

Now in resource server startup.cs file

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore().AddAuthorization().AddJsonFormatters();
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001"; //This is the identity server url where we are getting accesstoken.
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.ApiName = "openid";

       });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

In API mentioned like

```
[Route("api/")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class TestController : Controller


    // GET: api/v1/users/5
    [HttpGet("Hello")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> getMessage()
    {

        return Ok("Hello");
    }
```

}

When I pass the same accesstoken to the above API like below, getting 401. Do I need to pass anything. Or I am missing any validation.

[image: API Response]

Please help me.

Thank You.

Comment: Please consider using a [**MCVE** (**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: You need to show how you're sending the request to your api. Does it contain access token from IdentityServer?

Comment: @sttl06  - Yes, As you can see in the last screenshot (API Response). I am passing "Bearer <access_token>" in Headers. But how the server knows that this accesstoken is valid. Am i missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously I can't reproduce your problem due to the nature of the issue but since you can get an access token fine but still got 401; I think that means the access token you got is not valid for the api you're sending the request to.
My guess would be `.AddInMemoryApiResources(QuickstartIdentityServer.Config.GetApiResources())` is not configured properly e.g. `GetApiResources()` needs to return a `ApiResource` whose `Scopes` contain `openid` which is the scope you're using to request the access token. 
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yea by mistake i am referring  the same scope in GetIdentityResource instead of API Resource. Thank You So much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update your ConfigureServices method of resource server startup.cs file as shown in the following:

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = "openid";
            });


        // services.AddMvc();
    }
```

Comment: Yea that's the same thing.

Comment: Do we have to pass any other headers along with Authorization (accesstoken) header in Sample API